# Que signifie « aspect gauche » ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

Le livre *[Grammaire](https://www.amazon.fr/GRAMMAIRE-PRATIQUE-FRANCAIS-DAUJOURDHUI-Langue/dp/2010021347/ref=sr_1_4?__mk_fr_FR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&keywords=Mauger%20grammaire&qid=1564830942&s=gateway&sr=8-4) pratique du français d'aujourd'hui* par G. Mauger comporte la phrase :

> D'une manière générale, le français écrit et le français parlé préfèrent la forme active ou pronominale à la forme passive qui a parfois un aspect lourd ou gauche.

Quelle est la signification de l'aspect gauche ici ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En bref, c'est le contraire de *naturel*. *[Gauche](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/gauche)* veut dire « maladroit, difficile à manipuler, mal choisi ».

Dans le contexte d'une tournure linguistique, cela peut signifier que la tournure prend trop de temps à être dite ; qu'il est difficile de la prononcer ou d'en discerner le sens ; qu'elle est déroutante ; ou bien même qu'elle est peu fréquente, qu'elle est inusitée.

Cet « aspect » est subjectif. Par example, quelle est la différence entre ces trois possibilités ?

> On voit le soleil. *(forme active)*
>
> Le soleil se voit. *(forme pronominale)*
>
> Le soleil est vu. *(forme passive)*

On peut dire que la troisième est la plus courte et peut-être même la plus simple du point de vue de la grammaire !

Néanmoins, les opinions sur cet « aspect », bien qu'il soit difficile d'en connaître la cause, sont partagées *(hmm !)* par la majorité des locuteurs natifs. Il vaut mieux donc accepter le plus souvent ce qu'on dit quant à ce qui est le plus « naturel » ou « gauche ».

Comment: Merci infiniment ☺!

Comment: @jlliagre Merci ! (a) Pourquoi « être dite » au lieu de « dire » ? Y a-t-il des contextes où on peut dire « ça prend trop de temps à/pour [infinitif] » ? (b) Pourquoi pas d'espace avant le point-virgule, s'il y en a avant le point d'exclamation, etc.? (c) Pourquoi pas « on dirait » (I meant: "it looks like" or "it seems")

Comment: D'ou vient cette signification du mot gauche comme maladroit ? Et pourquoi son usage est considéré soutenu ?

Comment: (a) parce que ce n'est pas la tournure qui dit quelque chose (b) un excès de zèle de ma part. Je les remet ! (c) parce que la troisième forme est objectivement plus courte.

Comment: @dimitris En postulant que la majorité des gens sont droitiers, ce qu'ils font avec la main gauche est maladroit (qui à la même origine).

Comment: Merci. Maintenant je comprends.

Comment: On retrouve cette opposition en anglais (right or wrong) et en italien où gauche se dit *sinistra*...

Comment: Toujours la même question : pourquoi on retrouve et pas on trouve ?

Comment: Parce qu'on l'a déjà trouvée en français, et qu'on la trouve à nouveau dans d'autres langues, qu'on la **re**trouve donc.

Comment: C'est bon. Merci @jlliagre

Comment: (a) "ça prend trop de temps à dire" s'entend parfois mais c'est du français parlé familier, voire gauche ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre Merci des clarifications !

Comment: @jlliagre How natural would it be to say *dire ça prend trop de temps* ?

Comment: @LukeSawczak You'd need a pragmatic reason to front the infinitive, "ça prend trop de temps à dire" is the unmarked form. If you introduce a contrast, it would work: "Le dire, ça prend trop de temps, donc je préfère le montrer" (the accusative pronoun is required)