# Emploi de l'adjectif 'gauche'

Tags: expressions, usage

Question pas intelligente peut-être. Dans FSE, j'ai vu plusieurs fois l'expression 'tournure gauche' être utilisée. L'autre jour, parlant avec des collègues, j'ai dit :

> Cette dernière tournure me semble gauche.

Les collègues m'ont dit de ne pas utiliser l'adjectif 'gauche' pour désigner 'maladroit' ; sans grâce. Ont-ils raison ?

Comment: Adjectif déjà abordé ici: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30860

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C'est une tournure relativement soutenue qui est plutôt rare à l'oral. Donc bien que ce soit correct, de la part d'un locuteur non-natif ce sera probablement plus perçu comme une "erreur" de registre qu'une utilisation délibérée d'un mot soutenu.

De plus, je ne suis pas absolument sûr mais il me semble que *gauche* est plus péjoratif que *maladroit*. Dans un contexte d'enseignement, pour parler de la formulation d'un élève par exemple, il est à mon sens préférable et plus poli d'utiliser *maladroit*.

Comment: *Gauche* ne me semble pas plus péjoratif que *maladroit*. En revanche, peut-être que de nos jours, où l'on ne stigmatise plus les gauchers à l'école, il pourrait être perçu comme blessant à l'égard des gauchers ?

Answer (score 1):

C’est très correct, même soutenu.

Answer (score 1):

L'adjectif « gauche » est le plus parfait synonyme de « maladroit » ; on se sert d'ailleurs de ce dernier pour définir le premier. De plus, selon le TLFi, c'est le synonyme le plus approprié lorsque l'on décrit des manifestations artistiques, en particulier en ce qui concerne le langage ; « tournure gauche » est employé de façon synonyme avec « tournure maladroite ».

([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tournure+gauche%2Ctournure+maladroite&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctournure%20gauche%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctournure%20maladroite%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ctournure%20gauche%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctournure%20maladroite%3B%2Cc0))[image]

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gauche)) 2. [En parlant de manifestations de l'activité intellectuelle ou artistique] **Qui est maladroit, lourd, mal venu**.
> ♦ Il est indispensable (...) de connaître les formes rythmiques qu'on doit généralement éviter, comme étant vulgaires ou gauches, boiteuses ou heurtées (E. Durand, Traité harm., s. d., p. 81).
> ♦ Il suffirait de ce petit tableau de pauvre apparence, de mise en scène nulle, de couleur terne, de facture discrète et presque gauche, pour établir à tout jamais la grandeur d'un homme (Fromentin, Maîtres autrefois,1876, p. 355)
> ♦ Christophe était gêné pour entamer l'entretien. Après deux ou trois phrases gauches sur des sujets indifférents, il se jeta, avec une brusquerie un peu brutale, dans la question qui lui tenait au cœur. Rolland, J.-Chr., Adolesc., 1905, p. 245.
> ♦ SYNT. **Écriture, style gauche; caricature, commentaire, étude, mélodie, sculpture gauche; plaisanterie, réponse gauche**.
> ♦− Loc. impers., vieilli. Il est gauche de. Il est maladroit de.

> ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/gauche)) gauche adj. Qui est maladroit.

> ([Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/gauche/36281)) **Qui est maladroit, malhabile, emprunté**
> ♦ Un geste gauche.
> Synonymes : balourd - embarrassé - empêtré - empoté (familier) - gêné - godiche (familier) - gourde (familier) - inhabile - maladroit - malhabile - manchot (familier) - pataud - timide

En ce qui concerne la calligraphie, l'adjectif « maladroit » est préféré. ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%A9criture+gauche%2C%C3%A9criture+maladroite&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%C3%A9criture%20gauche%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%A9criture%20maladroite%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2C%C3%A9criture%20gauche%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%A9criture%20maladroite%3B%2Cc0))

[image]